# Populating 2 Access Tables From 1 Form

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am using Microsoft Access 2010 to make some processes easier for my small team. I have a form linked to a table (Table A) that users fill out to log information. I have a second table (Table B) that I want to copy the information to on submit or `GoToRecord.acNewRec` . 1 column in the first table I want to put in a specific value like "Type A". I have tried to do the following using the Click() on the Form connected to Form A:

```
Private sub ButtonSave_Click()
DoCmd.RunSQL ' INSERT INTO Table B (Item1, Item2, Item3) VALUES (FormItem1.Value, FormItem2.Value, FormItem3.Value)', True
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

This gave me a syntax error on the DoCmd.RunSQL
I also tried the following:

```
Private sub ButtonSave_Click()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "INSERT INTO Table B (Item1, Item2, Item3) VALUES (" & FormItem1.Value & "," & FormItem2.Value & "," & FormItem3.Value & ");"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL, True
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

This also says end expression on the INSERT TABLE line. 
I am so confused. I have googled all over Stack Exchange and tried all the other question suggestions and I keep getting the syntax or expression errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had some syntax issues when I was doing this and I had to do some more research and ask a friends who is VB centric.

The idea here is to insert the data from the form to the other table using SQL when you click the save button and it opens a new record. I needed the correct [ ] and "" in the correct areas.

```
Dim sSQL As String
sSQL = "Insert INTO [table2] (Item1, Item2, Item 3) VALUES (FormItem1.Value, FormItem2, Value, 'Title')"
DoCmd.RunSQL (sSQL)
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```